# If e.Cancel = true, when and where should I call base.OnClosing(e)?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosing(e); // here?

    if (cancelCondition)
    {
        base.OnClosing(e); // or here?
        e.Cancel = true;
        base.OnClosing(e); // or here?
    }

    base.OnClosing(e); // or here?
}
```

I've tried a few different places, and it seems to work anywhere, just wondering if it matters.  Does `base.OnClosing(e);` actually do anything?

Comment: Have you tried taking it out (Just having a blank override function) and see if it does anything?

Comment: Yes.  It doesn't "seem" to do anything.  I'm asking for confirmation.

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.onclosing.aspx):

> A type that derives from Window may override OnClosing. The overridden
>   method must call OnClosing on the base class if Closing needs to be
>   raised

In your case there seems to be no need to actually raise the `Closing` event, hence it doesn't matter if and where you call `base.OnClosing`.

---

You may however avoid to decide this in the first place if you do not override the `OnClosing` method, but simply add a `Closing` handler instead:

```
<Window ... Closing="Window_Closing">
    ...
</Window>

private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (cancelCondition)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be overriding `OnClosing` if you want to change how the closing event is fired.

1. If you want to execute code when the form is closing and have it run before any other `Closing` handlers, put your other code before `base.OnClosing`.
2. If you have code that you want to run after all other handlers have run, put that code after a call to `base.OnClosing`.
3. If you want to only conditionally run all of the other handlers, put `base.OnClosing` inside of some sort of conditional block so that it is only called when you want the other handlers to be run.

There is no one right answer for where it belongs in all cases.  You should put it wherever you want "all of the other event handlers" to be run, relative to whatever code your adding.